# How to sort Multi-Dimensional Array by 2 Column one by one - all in same order

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda, key

I like to have a Python *`2D`* **`array`** sorted by based on the first value than the second value. So, the sort function will first try to sort the items on the first column, if the value of the first column is same, then it will try to sort based on the second column value.

So, if I have a Python `array` like this-

```
[[1,6],[8,10],[15,18],[7,10],[1,3],[1,2]]
```

Then for the given array, the output should be like this-

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 6], [7, 10], [8, 10], [15, 18]]
```

I have to use [`python lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) function for this. What I have done is-

```
intervals = [[1,6],[8,10],[15,18],[7,10],[1,3],[1,2]]
................
................
intervals.sort(key=lambda x:x[1] and x[0])
```

After this, what I am getting is like this-

```
[[1, 6], [1, 3], [1, 2], [7, 10], [8, 10], [15, 18]]
```

If I am doing this-

```
intervals.sort(key=lambda x:x[0] and x[1])
```

Then I am getting this-

[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 6], [7, 10], [8, 10], [15, 18]]

Which is not as expected. Is there any way of finding what I need to have?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: What's wrong with regular `intervals.sort()` or `sorted(intervals)`?

Comment: It works great if my data has only 2 columns, but if my data has more than 2 columns and I like to sort only based on the first 2 columns, then it is not working. I have actually 5 columns but need to sort based on the first 2 columns only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `key` to limit the comparison to first two elements:

```
sorted(intervals, key=lambda x: x[:2])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 6], [7, 10], [8, 10], [15, 18]]
```

Which works fine with any number of elements in sublist:

```
import random

intv_random = [[*i, random.randint(1, 10000)] for i in intervals]

sorted(intv_random, key=lambda x: x[:2])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3378],
 [1, 3, 5035],
 [1, 6, 5732],
 [7, 10, 4474],
 [8, 10, 5862],
 [15, 18, 1176]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by myself. Actually what lambda function does is compare based on a key value. So to achieve my goal, I need to represent my 2D value with a number where the value should not go above int limit and should represent based on priorities, in this case, column 0, then column 1. So what I have done is like this-

```
intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]/2 + x[1]/10)
```

And getting-

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 6], [7, 10], [8, 10], [15, 18]]
```

And everything is working fine.

Comment: This would not return the desired result with `intervals = [[10, 1], [9,10]]`.

Comment: For this type of cases, I need to modify lambda function `x[0]/2 + x[1]/10` to `x[0] + x[1]/1000` or any other function